# Show that there exists $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that $AGA^{-1} \subset U$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers abd $p$ a prime number . Let $G\subset GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be a subgroup of order $p^n$. Let $U\subset GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be the subgroup that consists of all matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal and 0's below the diagonal . Show that there exists $A\in GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that $AGA^{-1} \subset U$

---

(edited)(thanks Chinnapparaj R and jgon )

okkk now i think i understand since $G$ be a subgroup of order $p^n$ so so it is a sylow subgroup of $GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $|GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)|=p^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\prod_{k=1}^n(p^k-1)$ . So $p^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ b the hieghest power which divide the order of $GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Again $U$ be subgroup of $GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $|U|=p^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$so $U$ is sylow-p group of $GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$Now by Sylow 2nd theorem$U$ and $G$ are conjugate which implies there exists $A\in GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that $$AGA^{-1} \subset U$$

Comment: You are correct that it can be proved with Sylow's theorems. It's not that $U$ has a Sylow-$p$ subgroup of that order, it is that $U$ *is* a Sylow-$p$ subgroup of that order. Then you're done, since all Sylow subgroups are conjugate, and every $p$-subgroup is contained in a Sylow-$p$ subgroup.

Comment: I don't get it; do you assume $m=n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Sylow's second theorem:

> If $P$ is a Sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$ and $Q$ is any  $p$ subgroup of $G$, then there exist $g \in G$ such that $Q \subseteq gPg^{-1}$

All the best for CMI exam!

Comment: thanks...but really tough exam for me ..